# Incorrect result when solving Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation in an annulus

Tags: differential-equations

Following an example from the documentation (DSolve/Scope/Elliptic Partial Differential Equations),
I try in version 13 on Windows 10

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] ==Sin[θ]^4;bc2 = u[3, θ] == 1;
DSolve[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}]
```

> `{{u[r, θ] -> Piecewise[{{3/8 + (5*Log[r])/(8*Log[3]), 1 <= r <= 3}}, Indeterminate]}}`

It's clear the above  result is not correct. For comparison,
Maple 2022 produces
$$u \! \left(r , \theta \right) = 
\frac{\left(328 r^{6}-26568 r^{2}\right) \ln \! \left(3\right) \cos \! \left(2 \theta \right)+\left(-r^{8}+6561\right) \ln \! \left(3\right) \cos \! \left(4 \theta \right)+19680 \left(\ln \! \left(3\right)+\frac{5 \ln \left(r \right)}{3}\right) r^{4}}{52480 \ln \! \left(3\right) r^{4}}.
 $$

Is there a symbolic, not numerical, workaround for this result of `DSolve`?

Comment: There is the typo with `bc1`, it should be `bc1 = u[1, θ] ==Sin[ θ]^4`, then we have wrong answer `3/8 + (5 Log[r])/(8 Log[3])`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: Fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a symbolic, not numerical, workaround for this result of
> DSolve

Here is a workaround.

Since $\sin^4(\theta) = \frac{3}{8}+\frac{\cos \left(4 \theta \right)}{8}-\frac{\cos \left(2 \theta \right)}{2}$ and since the pde is linear, we will solve the pde using each term above as the BC and then add the solutions.

This gives the same answer as Maple. Just make sure to use $u(3,\theta)=1$ once and set it to zero for the second and third solution so not to over add.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 1;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == 3/8;    
sol1 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == Cos[4*θ]/8;
sol2 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == -Cos[2*θ]/2;
sol3 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

sol = sol1 + sol2 + sol3 // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 sol /. {r -> 1.5, θ -> Pi/2}
 (* 0.841205 *)
```

Compare to Maple

```
restart;
pde:=VectorCalculus:-Laplacian(u(r,theta),'polar'[r,theta]);    
bc  := u(1,theta)=sin(theta)^4,u(3,theta)=1;
sol :=pdsolve([pde=0,bc],u(r,theta));
```

[image]

```
evalf(eval(rhs(sol),[r=1.5,theta=Pi/2]))

 #0.8412050606
```

For some reason, Mathematica had hard time with $\sin^4(\theta)$ as it stands.

```
 mmaPlot=ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], sol}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mapleSol = ((328*r^6 - 26568*r^2)*Log[3]*
      Cos[2*θ] + (-r^8 + 6561)*Log[3]*Cos[4*θ] + 
     19680*(Log[3] + (5*Log[r])/3)*r^4)/(52480*Log[3]*r^4);
maplePlot =  ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], mapleSol}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Reply to comments**

> Unfortunately, this is a trick made by hand. Think of bc1 = u[1, θ]
> ==Sin[θ]^41;

Mathematica can also solve this by breaking the terms and adding the solutions one by one.  I do not understand what you mean by `trick made by hand`. You asked for a workaround and I gave one. This can always be automated. Here is the same thing done for $\sin^8(\theta)$ for example. I do not feel now like doing it for $\sin^{41}(\theta)$ without writing automated function which will do it automatically.

Since

$$
\sin^8(\theta) = -\frac{7}{16} \cos (2 \theta )+\frac{7}{32} \cos (4 \theta )-\frac{1}{16} \cos (6 \theta )+\frac{1}{128} \cos (8 \theta )+\frac{35}{128}
$$

Then

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;

bc1 = u[1, θ] == 35/128;
bc2 = u[3, θ] == 1;
sol1 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == Cos[8*θ]/128;
sol2 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == -Cos[6*θ]/16;
sol3 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == (7*Cos[4*θ])/32;
sol4 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

bc2 = u[3, θ] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == -(7*Cos[2*θ])/16;
sol5 = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}];

sol = sol1 + sol2 + sol3 + sol4 + sol5 // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which gives same answer as Maple.  `DSolve` have hard time with trig function raised to  powers on them for some reason.

Compare to the wrong solution when done without breaking it up first

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == Sin[θ]^8;
bc2 = u[3, θ] == 1;
sol = DSolveValue[{leqn, {bc1, bc2}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Unfortunately, your statement "This can always be automated" is
> ungrounded

Here is a simple way to automate the expansion. May be this will ground it now.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
expand = Expand@TrigReduce[Sin[θ]^4];
expand = If[Head[expand] === Plus, expand = List @@ expand, {expand}];
assump = Assumptions -> 1 <= r <= 3;
sol = Total@First@Last@Reap@Do[
       Sow@If[n == 1,DSolveValue[{leqn, {u[3, θ] == 1, u[1, θ] == expand[[n]]}}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}, assump],
         DSolveValue[{leqn, {u[3, θ] == 0, u[1, θ] == expand[[n]]}}, 
          u[r, θ], {r, θ}, assump]
         ]
       , {n, 1, Length@expand}
       ];
sol = Simplify[sol]
ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], sol}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Think of bc1 = u[1, θ] ==Sin[θ]^41;

Here it is for `Sin[θ]^41`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
expand = Expand@TrigReduce[Sin[θ]^(41)];
expand = If[Head[expand] === Plus, expand = List @@ expand, {expand}];
assump = Assumptions -> 1 <= r <= 3;
sol = Total@First@Last@Reap@Do[
       Sow@If[n == 1,
         DSolveValue[{leqn, {u[3, θ] == 1, 
            u[1, θ] == expand[[n]]}}, 
          u[r, θ], {r, θ}, assump],
         DSolveValue[{leqn, {u[3, θ] == 0, 
            u[1, θ] == expand[[n]]}}, 
          u[r, θ], {r, θ}, assump]
         ]
       , {n, 1, Length@expand}
       ];
sol = Simplify[sol]
ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], 
  sol}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. Thank you. Unfortunately, this is a trick made by hand. Think of `bc1 = u[1, θ] ==Sin[θ]^41;` (forty one). Did you try to simplify the Maple's solution?

Comment: BTW, Maple solves `restart;
pde := VectorCalculus:-Laplacian(u(r, theta), 'polar'[r, theta]);
bc := u(1, theta) = sin(theta)^41, u(3, theta) = 1;
sol := pdsolve([pde = 0, bc], u(r, theta));`

Comment: Unfortunately, your statement "This can always be automated" is ungrounded.

Comment: Now I accept it (Life is a compromise.). It should be noticed that Maple produces a solution for `bc1 = u[1, θ] ==θ*(2*Pi-θ); bc2 = u[3, θ] == 1;` in a closed form, whereas Mathematica results in an analytic form (a series).